# A good way to implement a GUI/DB updatable table (CRUD)

Tags: java, database, swing, crud

I would like to present a database table in my Swing app.
Very simple table, it should display data that consists of one or a few tables in the database.

The user should be able to add, delete and update the table and then press save.
(not mandatory, it could just save each time he changes values )

- What is the recommended way to do that in the most efficient way?
- What are the recommended frameworks to start with?

Comment: *"What is the recommended way to do that in the most efficient way?"*  Well, there is always 'asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you' (which is the way I interpret such vague requests coupled with the terms 'best'/'most efficient'), but I'd hardly say it is *recommended*, especially not at SO.

Comment: i don't agree. especially when your a not an experienced programmer there are many best practices to implement things you might not be aware of. and there might be frameworks you have never heard of. an answer can always be a framework name, a designpattern or some copy and paste of own implementations. why not?

Comment: Well, even an old programmer could learn  a new tricks sometimes. I will explain my thoughts behind my original question. I usually do the full circle and use an observable bounded list and hibernate, dispatching my actions on user events. a whole lot of code.  But I am familiar with much RAD languages that do this in half amount of effort and code. Just came here to learn if there is a more rapid way to that in java. Sometimes the forum here just gives me a clue to look after new frameworks.

Comment: By the way, andrew, it is nice of you to disagree with the question but still edit and leave the original intention here :-)

Comment: @user450602 *"there are many best practices to implement things"*  Sure there are, that is why there is much research involved with asking a good question.  Part of it is to show your current understanding, perhaps comment on why you think this is the right or wrong approach, give people an idea at what level to pitch their reply (detailed or just keywords)..  This question shows little, if any of that research (or evidence). To the OP.  Please consider implementing the types of things I outlined above, as well as remembering to define 'good'/'efficient' etc.  They are very subjective terms.

Comment: And to both of you who are post 100 rep. & have been around for at least 1/4 year.  Hey, isn't it time to dump the 'jail-bird' numbers and edit your log-in details to a real name (or at lease a nic) instead of the numbers? O_o

Comment: Ok. My other option is to google best practices to GUI DB and get tons of answers, a lot with a very old technics. instead I come here because of the user rating system. I trust that the SO community will bubble up the most efficient and popular one.

Answer (score 4):

Usually a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) is used to render database data in a table format, you can see how [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

It is also recommended that you split your GUI and Database access logic into separate classes. Also, it might be a good idea to execute Database operations on a thread which is not the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT) since this might make your application's UI hang.

With regards to database access, you can use and ORM framework such as [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). It will allow you to connect to your database and retrieve information regardless of what database you are using. You can also change your underlying database at any point in time without you having to rewrite your SQL queries to fit the Database engine you are using.

You can use JFrames to create forms with which you can add and/or remove data.

Comment: Oh. So basically you are saying I must write it almost from scratch. I usually do exactly what you mentioned. Bind my jtable to an observable list and update the DB with either hibernate or sql. Isnt there a ready made framework yet for this?

Comment: @user450602: To my knowledge there aren't any frameworks which do this. I think that the main reason why is that the issue might be to trivial, so to speak, and many people do not consider it worth the effort. I might be wrong however.

Comment: I beg to differ. Binding a JTable to an observable list, binding the  correct columns, setting defaault names, dispatching events to the module, then binding it to a db for CRUD commands generates a lot of generic code. I was looking for some RAD FW that for instance accepts a JTable and DB Table and generates the whole connection. It does exist in other environments. I was just looking for an J2SE implemntation for that whole thing.